# Regular Expression for ProFTPd

Tags: regex, ftp, regular-language

I would really appreciate it, if somebody could help me out with my regular expression for ProFTPd's PathAllowFilter.

This is the regex I have so far: (.mp3|.aac|.m4a)$

Which allows only mp3s, aac, and m4a filetypes. But I would like to include the following, the filename may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, _ And the file-ending should be as stated above mp3, aac, and m4a, but it should be also allowed that it doesn't contain any extension.

So now is my thought, how can I all combine this in one regex? Maybe you guys have some good ideas :)

Thanks ahead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.(mp3|aac|m4a)?$
```

This requires the filename to contain only the symbols you listed (note: the `-` sign is at the end, so that it doesn't work as a meta-symbol), and the `?` makes the extension part optional.

Comment: Mhh that is weird, I tried that in my regex tester and this would be exactly how I think I need it, then I added it to the proftpd config, and he totally ignores it..  This is the documentation to it: [link](http://doc.mpv.ru/proftpd/Configuration.html#PathAllowFilter) Is there maybe a special way of adding it into the variable value?

Comment: Well, I visited your link, the possible cause of the problem may be that ProFTPd tries to match the entire pathname against provided regex. Try adding ".*/" (without quotes) in the beginning of this regex